# C# REST PayPal API - How to pass the custom variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've read about the the ability to pass a custom variable to along with my paypal payment
in order to identify later on.
Is it possible only through a client side request (paypal button + HTML form) or can I also achieve this ability using the server side REST Api (NOT the adaptive payments Api) for C#.
I searched a lot and will appreciate any help on this one.

Thnaks,
Ohad.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API does not provide a way to send pass through custom values.

Comment: aydiv,
Thanks for your answer.
Are you 100% positive? it seems like a pretty basic functionality.

Comment: The API does not have this feature yet. If your implementation involves redirecting buyer to the PayPal website for approval, you can tack the custom data to the return / cancel URLs. However, from a security point of view, your user can fudge the query parameters so you will need to implement appropriate checks.

Comment: The thing is that I need to store some details related to the transaction + Order-ID on my DB on realtime, and then when IPN message arrives to be able to identify it somehow.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Can't you just store and look up this information in your db with PayPal's payment id as the key?

Comment: Paypal IPN message doesn't seem to include payment ID
(PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX formatted string)